# Suppress "autoplay" when external USB drive connected

Tags: usb-host-mode, auto-start

On some phones, when an external USB drive is connected to the phone, there is sort of an autoplay function where it automatically brings up the "My Files" screen. Is there a way to suppress this?

This occurs on my Note 2 with Android version 4.1.2, but not on my Note 1 with version 4.0.4. Just to be clear, I want the drive to automatically mount in the background as usual, but just not bring up the "My Files" screen. I have an app that expects a USB drive to be plugged in and searches for specific file types and this behavior is annoying because it takes the screen away from my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping to be able to programmatically suppress the default "My Files" system app from starting when a USB storage device is plugged in, but it looks like it is not possible.

However, I did find a workaround. First I installed a new file manager/explorer from the market (I used ES File Explorer). Then I went to Android Settings -> Applications and then selected the My Files app from the list and disabled it. Now it no longer interferes with my own application that I am developing for my USB storage device. Not the ideal solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Deep sleeping apps will never run in the background.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exhange! Could you explain a little more about this post? Does it mean that putting an app on deep sleep may suppress the autoplay when the Android device is connected to the external USB storage? Or are you having an issue with deep sleeping apps?